# jQuery - How to set a select which doesn't exist yet

Tags: jquery

I have the following HTML:

```
...
<div>
    <select id="select_1" name="select_1">
        <option value="1" selected="selected">Option 1</option>
        <option value="2">Option 2</option>
        ...
    </select>
    <a id="add_1">Add New</a>
</div>
<div>
    <select id="select_2" name="select_2">
        <option value="1" selected="selected">Option 1</option>
        <option value="2">Option 2</option>
        ...
    </select>
    <a id="add_2">Add New</a>
</div>
...
```

When I click on the "Add New" link a new div with a select is created. I need to set that new select, but don't know how to do it beacuse it doesn't exist yet. I'm trying with something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('[id^=add_]').on('click', function() {
        var new_select = $(this).parent().next().find('[id^=select_]'); // This doesn't work. Any way to do it?
        ...
        });
    });
});
```

Thanks.

Comment: Made a number of changes and suggested improvements and posted a JSFiddle for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Use a delegated event handler, attached to a non-changing ancestor element, for the add buttons.
- Use classes for the add button (you do not need IDs there)
- Use `closest` in preference to `parent` to allow for future DOM changes.
- Calculate the new name/id based on the number of existing items
- Use a template div, stored in a dummy script block for convenience.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/455ahpyw/4/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('click', '.add', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var $div = $(this).closest('div');
        // Append the template and replace the id with the existing number of these +1
        var id = "select_" + ($("[id^=select_]").length + 1);
        var $template = $($('#template').html());
        $template.find('select').attr('id', id).attr('name', id);
        $div.after($template);
    });
});
```

**Explanation of delegated event handlers:**

They work by listening for the specified event to bubble up to a non-changing ancestor, *then* they apply the jQuery selector, *then* they apply the function to any matching elements *that caused the event*. This means they will work on elements that exist at event time and not just at registration time (which is when a "normal" handler connects).